# End Portal in FTB teleports to random location in the overworld

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-direwolf20

This issue has happened twice now on 2 different worlds.

I've found the end portal, put the eyes of ender all around, the portal effect appears, I jump in, then I get teleported to a random location in the overworld, with a nether portal behind me.

Does the End Portal work differently in FTB? This issue is almost identical to the nether issue I had previously (allow nether setting was false in the config). I've looked for an allow end setting but can't find one.

Comment: Which mod pack are you using?

Comment: The direwolf20 mod pack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your server's `bukkit.yml` file (generally found in the same directory as your `server.properties`) you need to edit the line:

> allow-end: false

To

> allow-end: true

And then restart the server.

Comment: Ahh, I was looking in server.properties. I'll do this now, although last time I tried restarting the world after a End attempt, the whole server got broken :P.

Comment: Unfortunately config changes aren't hot-deployed, so there's no (easy) way to get around needing a server restart